# I'm using django serializers to deserialize a json with nested elements but can't get the right classes

Tags: python, django, json, mongodb, deserialization

I would like to deserialize a json request into class serializers but can't get the correct wrapper class.

This is the json I use:

```
{
  "NewData":
  {
    "UserID":"12345",
    "CommunicationId":"11111",
    "SessionId":"22222",
    "StartTime":"2013-08-12",
    "EndTime":"2013-08-13",
    }
}
```

What should the class serializers look like?

I have the following class, but I need a wrapper class.

```
class CommSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    '''Serializer for Comm documents
    '''
    UserID = serializers.IntegerField()
    CommunicationId = serializers.IntegerField()
    SessionId = serializers.IntegerField()
    StartTime = serializers.CharField()
    EndTime = serializers.CharField()

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """Create or update a new Comm (dict) instance.
        """
        return dict(attrs)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at json.loads() ?  Converts your JSON into a dictionary.

Comment: I have, but it creates a generic dictionary which is not typed and not validated. This is a solution, but less preferred. Thanks,